# React equivalent to Blazor singelton pattern

Tags: react.js, typescript, blazor

I'm refactoring a code-base in React, and our design team have decided to move a button out of its usual flow and instead to a component that's very much not a descendant of the logic.

I'm relatively new to React; however, if I was doing this in Blazor I know I could just create a singleton object and use dependency injection to allow the two unrelated components to communicate. I gave it a try to do something similar in React.

(Design team have moved the "New Chat" button out of the chat component—where the logic is, to the Sidebar—which is outside the component hierarchy.)

My Singleton equivalent is:
newchat.ts

```
let onNewChat: (() => void) | undefined = undefined;

export const setNewChat = (newChat: () => void) => onNewChat = newChat;
export const clearNewChat = () => onNewChat = undefined;
export const hasNewChat = () => !!onNewChat;
export const callNewChat = () => {
    onNewChat?.call(this);
}

export const event = (() => {
    const events = new Set<React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>>();
    const add = (event: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>) => {
        events.add(event);
    }
    const remove = (event: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>) => {
        events.delete(event);
    }
    const process = (value: boolean) => {
        events.forEach(e => e(value));
    }
    return {
        add, remove, process
    }
})();
```

Inside the chat page:
chat.tsx

```
import { setNewChat, clearNewChat, event } from "../../interfaces/newchat"

export const Chat = () => {
    const [answers, setAnswers] = useState<ChatMessage[]>([]);
    const [activeSession, setActiveSession] = useState<SavedChatResponse | undefined>(undefined);
    
    const startNewChat = () => {
        setAnswers([]);
        setActiveSession(undefined);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        event.process(answers.length === 0 && !activeSession?.chat_id);
    }, [answers, activeSession]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setNewChat(startNewChat);
        return () => {
            clearNewChat();
        };
    }, []);

    return (<>...</>)
}
```

And inside my sidebar:
sidebar.tsx

```
import { event, callNewChat } from "../../interfaces/newchat"
export const SideBar = ({...}: Props) => {
    const [newChatDisabled, setNewChatDisabled] = useState<boolean>(true);
    useEffect(() => {
        event.add(setNewChatDisabled);

        return () => {
            event.remove(setNewChatDisabled);
        }
    }, []);

   return(
       <>
           ...
           <div className={styles.newchat}>
                <div role="button" 
                     aria-labelledby={newchatId} 
                     className={`${styles.button} ${newChatDisabled && "disabled"}`} 
                     onClick={callNewChat}
                >
                    <ReactSVG className={styles.add} src={add} />
                    <label id={newchatId}>New Chat</label>
                </div>
            </div>
       </>
}
```

So far it appears to work, but is there another way to do this, and are there any improvements I could make?